# Ruby Sequel left outer join query

Tags: ruby, sequel

I have a more complex query (does not work)

```
query.select_all(:table_1).select_more(:col_1)
.left_outer_join(:table_2, table_1_id: :id, col_1: 1, 
Seqel.lit('col_2 > ?', 1.week.ago)
```

I need to compare `col_2` like this:

```
"col_2 > '2018-01-01 10:10:10'"
```

it is easy to write whole query as custom sql, but I would like to chain methods and so far I couldn't succeed in adding the above.

expected result ~:

```
"SELECT `table_1`.*, `table_2`.`col_1` FROM `table_1`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `table_2` 
ON (
`table_2`.`table_1_id` = `table_1`.`id`
AND
`table_2`.`col_1` = 1 
AND 
`table_2`.`col_2` > '2018-01-01 10:10:10')"
```

---

I used `with_sql` but it ignores other scopes.
Also I tried:

```
 .left_outer_join("`table_2` ON (`table_2`.`table_1_id` =
 `table_1`.`id` AND `table_2`.`col_1` = 1 AND `table_2`.`col_2` >
 '2017-09-28 06:49:53 UTC')")
```

Problem in last one is that it wraps that whole string with extra ``` `` ```

---

what worked for me:

```
.left_outer_join(:table_2, 
Sequel.lit('table_2.table_1_id = table_1.id AND table_2.col_1 = ? 
AND table_2.col_2 > ?', id, date))
```

but is there a way to accomplish it without using string queries?

Comment: Why not execute that sql in `#find_by_sql` method of rails ?

Comment: I could use it but I need to chain more scopes. `find_by_sql` does not seem to work with sequel.

Answer (score 1):

```
.left_outer_join(:table_2, :table_1_id=>:id, :col_1=>id){Sequel[:table_2][:col_2] > date}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and/or **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

This is might be a bit cleaner:

```
.left_outer_join(:table_2,
   table_2.where(table_1_id: 'table_1.id')
          .where(col_1: id)
          .where('col 2 > ?', date)
 )
```

Comment: it does not change much

Comment: what is `query` defined as in your example?  Can you paste the output of your current example and the one I posted?

Comment: actually I put this as second argument and put inside rest of string query and it worked: `.left_outer_join(:table_2, Sequel.lit('table_2.table_1_id = table_1.id AND table_2.col_1 = ? AND table_2.col_2 > ?', id, date))`, it 's cool it worked but would be nice to have more sequel-like solution

Comment: I updated my answer, but glad you figured it out., you should post your solution too.

Answer (score 0):

I will post my own answer, but will not accept it because I think it could be done better.

```
.left_outer_join(:table_2, 
Sequel.lit('table_2.table_1_id = table_1.id AND table_2.col_1 = ? 
AND table_2.col_2 > ?', id, date))
```

So waiting for other suggestions.

Comment: you should be able to chain `AND` statements with `.where()` see my updated answer